# Printable content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i would like to create an application that needs to have the option to print things. I would like to ask if there is a standard way of handling such situations in Rails, or it's just a specific layout to be served when printing is asked. Is there a gem, or a good approach on doing such a thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ved used the [WickedPDF gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) in the past with much success.  It's based on `wkhtmltopdf` and what I really like about it is the PDF is generated based on a view template that's standard ERB (possibly HAML) and CSS.

It's better than going with `prawn` in my opinion as the template markup/styling can be reused for the PDF itself.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://www.kuwaitobesity.com/agenda) I worked on a while back; the generated PDF uses a template that's almost identical to the same public facing view.